# Discrete distribution that look Normal

Tags: probability

I have a "simple" doubt but I have never found an answer. If I have a discrete Random Variable that looks Normal when I make the Histogram, I mean, it is symetric, and it looks like Normal, can I treat it as a Normal distribution?
This question is because I have seen many examples of discretes distributions being treated as Normal when their histograms look like the "Gaussian bell". But this is not correct right?, because to treat is as a normal distribution the Random Variable must be continuous. Thanks for you attention and anwer.

Comment: See the CLT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: It is not uncommon for macroscopic behaviour of discrete random systems to have Gaussian behaviour in the limit.

Comment: As an approximation it often works.  It is very common to use a normal approximation to the binomial distribution.  It is not perfect, but it is very good.  It is an approximation.

Comment: Okok, I think now I can justify why I use the Normal distribution to model my Random Variable. The thing is that I have 365 observations of the demand of one item and since it is discrete,I thought that using the Normal Distribution would be a mistake, even though the histogram looks like the Gaussian Bell. But now I know I can do it due to the CLT. Thanks a lot for your help.